# does cgi-bin have something like servlet filters

Tags: cgi

Does cgi scripts have something like servlet filters. I.e. a piece of code that is given the opportunity to see and or modify a request before and or after it is processes by the "real" script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are programming a CGI script via an apache module, then it is possible. mod_perl, for example, gives hooks into that. Regular CGI, where apache calls an outside process to deal with the script - nope. Sorry.